# How to decide the thread numbers when loading files concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing coding to solve a problem like this.
There are about 50 - 200 small files. And total size of these files will not be very big. And my goal is concurrently loading them into one table.

And it seems the code works quite well and it really works faster than using single thread.

However, I just a bit not sure. Is it the best choice to open as much as threads as the file numbers?

Another thing is I just use the simplest way to do the multi-thread.
Is this also the best choice?

Any suggestion or advice is appreciated!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
                        synchronized (threads[i]) {
                            threads[i].run();
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; ++i) {
                        synchronized (threads[i]) {
                            try {
                                threads[i].join();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                 return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: `run()` doesn't start thread :)

Comment: I'd expect two threads to be the most efficient solution, that means that one thread can process the currently fetched data while the other thread has issued a read command and is waiting for the disk to return it.

Comment: I somehow doubt that multi threading that code would improve performance by much anyhow - you're clearly IO limited there. But that just shows that learning how to measure stuff is important - the placebo effect is strong here :D

Comment: @ClarkBao Your code **IS** single threaded. If you claim to see any improvements compared to the other single threaded version, you'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Voo I then tried to change to use ExecutorService as Tudor said, And using two threads as I have only two processors in my PC. It seems to be faster a bit. But if I open more threads, some times the in-memory derby DB will complain it is waiting for a lock, So this makes me doubt its concurrent ability. I also met trouble to seperate read file function due to the load procedure it provides only allows me input the file name. Unless I want to rewrite it myself.

Comment: So what I can thinking I will not really switch to multi-thread unless I see it passes enough tests.

Comment: Yeah as I was saying in my first post: You're IO limited and throwing more threads at the HDD won't make much difference at all and may even make it slower. Derby handles multi threaded code just fine - IF you do it correctly (don't use the same connection from several threads, deadlocks, etc.). Imho the most sensible approach here is to use one thread to store data in a queue and let one/several threads process the incoming data (depending how much work it is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing: Threads are started with `start()`, not `run()`. `run()` will make them run serially on the main thread.

Second thing: It's pointless to start 200 threads. You are only wasting time and system resources without getting any speedup (you cannot be faster by a factor larger than the number of processor cores). Just use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and queue up tasks using `submit`. This managed thread pool will take care of selecting the correct number of threads depending on your system resources.

Third thing: If you are just processing some files independently, you do not need any locks. Especially in your example you are using locks to start and join threads, which has no (positive) effect.

**Edit**: Probably the best solution in your case is to just implement a single-producer (to read from disk), multiple-consumer (to process the files) system.

Comment: In theory, I agree. However, the bulk-insert built-in procedure of Derby is quite self-contained. It is quite hard to seperate the read file from this code. Also in the profile result ,most of the work load and time consuming part is still paid on the DB bulk-insert itself.

Comment: public static void SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE(
 String  schemaName,
    String  tableName,
 String  fileName,
 String  columnDelimiter,
 String  characterDelimiter,
 String  codeset,
 short   replace)
        throws SQLException
    {
  Connection conn = getDefaultConn();
  try{
   Import.importTable(conn, schemaName , tableName , fileName ,
                               columnDelimiter , characterDelimiter, codeset, 
                               replace, false);
  }catch(SQLException se)
  {
   rollBackAndThrowSQLException(conn, se);
  }
  conn.commit();
 }//source code ofderby

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't start any thread. So your measurements must be wrong. Starting a thread is done using the `start()` method. It's also not very clear what your synchronized blocks are supposed to do. A synchronized block is used to make sure some mutable shared state is accessed by only one thread at a time. But you don't access any mutable shared state inside your synchronized blocks.

I doubt loading files from a single disk would be faster with multiple threads than with just once, because you'll pay the cost of context switches, and you'll also pay the cost of forcing the disk to change its reading location frequently rather than reading a whole file at once.